# What's an accessible way to group items within a radiogroup? (HTML5/WAI-ARIA)

Tags: html, forms, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a page I'm trying to code where the user has to select one from a number of options, presented as a grid of thumbnails. On similar pages, I've used `role="radiogroup"` and `role="radio"` (and appropriate scripting, labelling, etc), and that worked well - the difference with this one is that there are multiple sections within the larger radiogroup.

**Edit, to clarify:** I'd rather use native radio buttons, as several people have pointed out. I may not be able to because this is a big angular app with a lot of weird baggage I have to work around, but I'm looking into it. That said, whether they're `role="radio"` or `type="radio"`, my question is specifically about *the best way to communicate that some of them are grouped together*.

The user can pick only one option, from any of these sections. The structure is along these lines:

---

**Choose an image**

Artist 1

- Image A
- Image B

Artist 2

- Image C
- Image D

---

So basically, I'm looking for a way to preserve the "artist" context while moving through the image options. Something like `optgroup` from the `select` element. I've tried `fieldset`, which kind of works; I'm wondering if that's the best way to go?

Here's what I currently have, structure-wise. (Appropriate focus and keyboard management will be added as needed via JS.)

```
<form id="select-design" aria-label="Design Options">
<h2>Choose an image</h2>

<div role="radiogroup" id="collections-list" aria-label="Options" tabindex="0">

    <fieldset id="group-1">
        <legend>Artist: Jack Kirby</legend>

        <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200x200/bada55/fff" alt="Cool Picture">
        </div>

        <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200x200/0de/fff" alt="Also Cool Picture">
        </div>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="group-2">
        <legend>Artist: Kevin Maguire</legend>

        <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200x200" alt="Nice Art">
        </div>

        <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200x200/0cd/fff" alt="Nicer Art">
        </div>
    </fieldset>

</div>
```

And here it is as a [codepen](http://codepen.io/jackmakesthings/pen/jqpPXo).

One issue I'm seeing is that with my current html, it reads the first radio button as "2 of 3" - I guess it's treating the legend as a radioitem by default due to its placement in the DOM. Overall, it works, but I feel like it could be better.

Any thoughts?

Would be especially grateful if any screen-reader users can weigh in on this one.

Comment: I've always used fieldset, so I'd be curious to know if there's a better way.

Comment: Sorry, but why don't you use `<input type="radio">`? Just because of the image? I'm asking because my JAWS latest version behaves really weird here. It might be a JAWS bug, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agree with @stringy about using native radio buttons (see [first rule of ARIA use](http://w3c.github.io/aria-in-html/#rule1)) But if you must create custom radio buttons you need to use the aria attribute [aria-setsize](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-setsize) on each control (also suggest looking at the [accessible custom control checklist](http://w3c.github.io/aria-in-html/#checklist)):

```
<fieldset id="group-1">
        <legend>Artist: Jack Kirby</legend>

        <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-setsize="2">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200x200/bada55/fff" alt="Cool Picture">
        </div>

        <div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1" aria-setsize="2">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200x200/0de/fff" alt="Also Cool Picture">
        </div>

    </fieldset>
```

In regards to the outer `<div>` This in itself is not a `radiogroup` it groups 2 sets of radiogroups (which don't need to be specified using `role=radiogroup` as you are using `fieldset/legend`)

So suggest using `role=group` and removing the `tabindex=0` as the `div`  container isn't itself an interactive object and should not be in the focus order:

```
<div role="group" id="collections-list" aria-label="Options">
```

@jack if all radiobuttons are part of same group, then they should be containing within a single `fieldset/legend` or `role=radiogroup` with accessible name (via `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby`) then wrap each of the 3 sub groups in

```
<div role=group aria-label="whatever">
```

Comment: Does treating each fieldset as its own radiogroup work in this instance, though? I understood 'radiogroup' as meaning the set of radio buttons that you can pick a single option from - so if there were 3 radiogroups on the page, you'd be able to pick 3 choices, one for each. Whereas what I have is more like 3 groups that all map to the same input - you should only be able pick one picture out of all the ones on the page, not one per set. Like I said, the closest functionality equivalent that comes to mind is a select with optgroups.

Comment: @jack ok so all radiobuttons are part of same group, then they should be containing within a single fieldset/legend or role=radiogroup with accessible name (via aria-label or aria-labelldby) then wrap each of the 3 sub groups in <div role=group aria-label="whatever">

Comment: Cool, that makes sense. I'm going to accept your answer; would you mind adding that comment to the body of the answer so future readers don't overlook it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @jack - added as requested

Comment: Nesting a group inside a radiogroup doesn't work that well in VoiceOver.  It only reads out the nearest group.  So the user will never hear the label for radiogroup, and only hear the sub-label for the artist.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you are relying on `<div>` elements to create your form instead of standard form elements. If you change to `<input type="radio">` as Andre suggests, you can use a [matching name attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes) to associate the radios.

This way the keyboard and screenreader software can tell how many inputs there are in the group even if they are separated by other markup. All of the HTML form elements have full keyboard support and focus states, which reduces the amount of scripting you have to do.

Inputs should also have a label, so that's a natural home for your image and any other details of the option. And you tell the browser (and therefore screenreaders) which label belongs to which input by pairing their for/id attributes.

E.g.

```
<p>Artist: Jack Kirby</p>
<input type="radio" name="A1" value="p1" id="p1">
<label for="p1"><img src="pic1.jpg" alt="Title of artwork" /></label>
<input type="radio" name="A1" value="p2" id="p2">
<label for="p2"><img src="pic2.jpg" alt="Title of artwork" /></label>

<p>Artist: Kevin Maguire</p>
<input type="radio" name="A1" value="p3" id="p3">
<label for="p3"><img src="pic3.jpg" alt="Title of artwork" /></label>
<input type="radio" name="A1" value="p4" id="p4">
<label for="p4"><img src="pic4.jpg" alt="Title of artwork" /></label>
```

Different HTML elements carry different useful information to the browser, and div elements are mostly just an empty box to contain other elements. ARIA works best when you've got unique widgets you can't replicate with meaningful markup, but it's much easier to make things accessible when you can use the right HTML for the job. MDN's HTML guide that I linked above has heaps of useful information for this kind of thing.

Comment: Agreed! Trust me, I'd much rather use inputs and native features. The html as it currently exists is due to a lot of Angular baggage in the app I'm working on; if I can make it work as real radio inputs, I will. My question was more about whether there's a way to say "pick one of these 9 inputs, from any of these three groups of 3", for example. In your version of my code, I believe the p tags would get largely skipped over by a user tabbing through, no? I'm looking for a way to associate them with their related inputs.

Comment: Ah I see! In that case I've upvoted Steve Faulkner's answer as that's what will work best I believe!